# Celery, Django, Eventlet, django-celery-beat "raise NotImplementedError("unsupported platform")"

Tags: python, django, celery, eventlet, django-celery-beat

Celery, Eventlet, django-celery-beat for a project, but when give the bellow command

```
celery -A app worker -P eventlet -c 100 -l info  --logfile=celery.log
```

I get the following error

```
(sample_app) neerajgoyal@Neerajs-MacBook-Pro app % celery -A app worker -P eventlet -c 100 -l info  --logfile=celery.log Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/bin/celery", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 13, in main
    maybe_patch_concurrency()   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 140, in maybe_patch_concurrency
    patcher()   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 101, in _patch_eventlet
    import eventlet.debug   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 79, in <module>
    setattr(dns, pkg, import_patched('dns.' + pkg))   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 61, in import_patched
    return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 132, in import_patched
    return inject(   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 109, in inject
    module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dns/asyncquery.py", line 38, in <module>
    from dns.query import (   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dns/query.py", line 63, in <module>
    import httpcore   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._api import request, stream   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._sync.connection_pool import ConnectionPool   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .connection import HTTPConnection   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .._synchronization import Lock   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_synchronization.py", line 13, in <module>
    import trio   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._core import TASK_STATUS_IGNORED as TASK_STATUS_IGNORED  # isort: skip   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ._local import RunVar   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/_local.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import _run   File "/Users/neerajgoyal/miniconda3/envs/sample_app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/_run.py", line 2548, in <module>
    raise NotImplementedError("unsupported platform") NotImplementedError: unsupported platform
```

Let me know what else details are required as stuck on this, I installed python 3.10 and other dependencies through **miniconda** using **"conda-forge"** as channel.

Comment: Can you try using gevent and prefork pools and see if the same error occurs. `kqueue` should be present in macos. Can you also retry installing packages again? Community suggest this could even arise with wrong order of package installation.

Comment: an update on this, things work if i remove `django_celery_beat` package and its references from the project. @LemonReddy , if I try to install it it asks me to downgrade `importlib-metadata` from **6.8.0** to  **4.13.0** not sure if that's causing it to break.

Comment: its working with `gevent` as worker, and also with `prefork` @LemonReddy

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling that trio is not running on a supported platform. Celery also do not support trio yet.

Comment: raise an issue with `django-celery-beat` [link](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/668) let's see what they have to say